# manipulate the scrollBar of a tableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

In my javafx application I have a table view where data were shown and also where user can add data by double click on an empty area.
But my problem is where the user add some data and the scrollbar of the table view appear, it show just the rows that contain data, and there is no more empty area for user to add more data,
My question is: there is any method to manipulate the scrollbar of the table view so that I can always have an empty area

Comment: Edit your question to include either an image which demonstrates the issue or an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (or both).  If you don't have enough reputation to include an image in your question, you can post the image on [http://imgur.com](http://imgur.com) and link to your posted image from your question.

Comment: there is the image before(there is empty area ) http://imgur.com/4jWi7At      And after adding some data, there is no empty area http://imgur.com/TiCZduc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout is managed by layout panes.  These layout managers implement layout algorithms which respect constraints placed on nodes and containers of nodes.  So to have an area of the UI always visible, you have to choose an appropriate layout pane to place the component inside and set the appropriate constraints to ensure that the component is always visible.  How to do so will vary depending on the enclosing layout pane and the component being added.

Here is an example which creates an always visible area placed below replicates something like the images you link in your comment on your question.  You could implement a controller for the FXML which provides implementations of the drag event handlers so that when somebody drags some content into the "Empty area to add data", relevant data is added to the table.

[image: screenshot]

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="277.0" prefWidth="215.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TableView prefHeight="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="96.0" text="C1" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="93.0" text="C2" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onDragDetected="#dragDetected" onDragDone="#dragDone" onDragDropped="#dragDropped" onDragEntered="#dragEntered" onDragExited="#dragExited" onDragOver="#dragOver" prefHeight="70.0" text="Empty area to add data" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" VBox.vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

See also:

- [Is there an easier (lighter) way to center text in a "zone" with JavaFX 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075994/is-there-an-easier-lighter-way-to-center-text-in-a-zone-with-javafx-8/28077333#28077333)

Comment: it's works, but what I wish, is to hide the scrollbar of the table view(I did it with CSS) then  add a new scrollbar, but I don't know how to use it