# Is there an easier (lighter) way to center text in a "zone" with JavaFX 8?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So, first things first, I have achieved what I wanted, and that is, display some amount of text in the center of a "zone". Screenshot (upper right corner):

[image]

Now, the problem I have is how I achieved this... This is the FXML extract for the whole tab:

```
<Tab text="Statistics" closable="false">
    <SplitPane orientation="VERTICAL" dividerPositions="0.5">
        <SplitPane orientation="HORIZONTAL" dividerPositions="0.5">
            <GridPane gridLinesVisible="false">
               <!-- snip -->
            </GridPane>
            <!-- HERE -->
            <BorderPane>
                <center>
                    <Label text="No information"/>
                </center>
            </BorderPane>
        </SplitPane>
        <TableView fx:id="stats">
            <!-- snip -->
        </TableView>
    </SplitPane>
</Tab>
```

As you can see, in order to achieve something which intuitively should be simple (display some text in the center of a zone), I had to create a `BorderPane` and put a `Label` in its `<center>`; and I didn't even have to specify that the text on the label should be centered...

The other things I have tried are:

- put the `Label` itself: then the divider of the `ScrollPane` would be blatanly ignored; the left side would expand to the full width of the `Scene` (is that it?) minus the width of the divider plus the text of the label, and what is more, the text would be at the top of the zone;
- enclose it with an `AnchorPane`: while this would indeed keep the size of the zone, the text would appear on the top left corner and not in the center.

Is there an easier solution than the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) rather than a [BorderPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html).  By default a StackPane will center any node you put in it.  To me, this is the simplest, most intuitive solution.

```
<StackPane>
    <Label text="No information"/>
</StackPane>
```

Another way to handle it is to set constraints on the label itself so that the label will expand to fill a resizable area and center itself within the area:

```
<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" 
           prefHeight="400.0" 
           prefWidth="600.0" 
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <items>
      <StackPane />
      <Label alignment="CENTER" 
             maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" 
             maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" 
             text="Label" />
   </items>
</SplitPane>
```

If it is a multi-line label (e.g. it has `\n` new lines in the text or the available width forces a wrap because you constrain the width and set `wrapText="true"`), then you need an additional setting to center the multi-line text within the label: `textAlignment="true"`. `textAlignment` is different from `alignment`; in particular, `textAlignment` applies only to multi-line controls.

Comment: Uhwell, using your suggestions I just replaced the code with `<StackPane><Label text="No information"/></StackPane>` and it indeed achieved the same effect... That difference in default between the different panes is killing me, but your solution did the trick for me! I still quite don't understand why however...

Comment: I'd try to explain it, but sometimes it is hard understand what people don't understand.  After you have worked with a technology for a while, a lot of things just seem obvious, even though the things are not obvious to somebody new to the technology.

Comment: Ohwell, answer accepted... I'll try and figure out what there is to figure out later about default behaviors! Thanks for your answer. Note that it doesn't prevent you from providing some useful hints ;)